# extend or include multiple instances TWIG

Tags: php, twig

I am using Twig to use as templating engine and i have a common right sidebar that shall be included on all pages.

**_base.twig**

```
/* Page HTML header */
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
/* Page HTML Footer */
```

**index.twig**

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}
    {% block content %}
         <div id="left-bar">Dynamic Content</div>
         <div id="right-bar">Static Content</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**about.twig**

```
    {% block content %}
         <div id="left-bar">Dynamic Content</div>
         <div id="right-bar">Static Content</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

.... so on for many pages.. I want `right-bar` to be a external page and shall be included every page as content is same always.

I tried using `{% extends %}` two times but Twig fails as i read that multiple extends are not allowed. So any solutions please.

Comment: have you tried to use 'use' tag ? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Twig, you have many possibilities for solving your problem :

**A/ The parent solution** Official doc is [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html)

This solution renders the contents of the parent block in your child Block.

**_base.twig**

```
/* Page HTML header */
{% block content %}
    <div id="left-bar">Dynamic Content</div>
    <div id="right-bar">Static Content</div>
{% endblock %}
/* Page HTML Footer */
```

**index.twig**

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

**about.twig**

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

**other.twig**

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    <div> If you don't place the parent twig attribute, your menu can't appear and will be overrided</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**B/ The Include Solution** Official doc is [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)

This solution create another block, and call the block in the child block.

**_base.twig**

```
/* Page HTML header */
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
/* Page HTML Footer */
```

**navBar.twig**

```
<div id="left-bar">Dynamic Content</div>
<div id="right-bar">Static Content</div>
```

**index.twig**

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ include('navBar.twig') }}\]
{% endblock %}
```

**about.twig**

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ include('navBar.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

If you use the Symfony2 Framework, you can already use the `{{ render(controller('')) }}` [you can see a sample [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html)] for call a specific controller, himself call a twig view... it's very useful if you want to load a dynamic values in your block, but is less effective than a `{{ include('') }}`...

For me, the B solution is the best, but both solutions work.

Comment: Ok. I shall try that. It is SLIM that i am using. And one more thing my changes in CSS are not being reflected. Is there anything do with CSS?

Comment: That depend where is include your CSS File ^^
But, if your CSS is include in your page (you can see the source code of your page) generally, you've no problem with that...